# Barra de Progresso de Requisição Ajax

Tags: ajax, progress-bar

Gostaria de saber como faço pra criar uma barra de progresso de uma requisição ajax que mostre o quanto foi processado, meio que o intervalo entre o envio da requisição e o done. Estou utilizando a função xhr do ajax mas está me retornando sempre 100%, não sei se tem algo a ver com estar em localhost ou versão do jquery ou ajax. Vou deixar abaixo o código da requisição.

```
function sendSelectedBankSlips() {

        var selectedBankSlips = new Array();
        $("#bankSlipsTable input[name=check]:checked").each(function() {
            selectedBankSlips.push($(this).val());
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{ route('bankSlips.pull') }}",
            data: {
                selectedBankSlips
            },
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#pullBankSlips #bankSlipsContent").html('');
                $("#pullBankSlips .modal-header, .modal-body, .modal-footer").addClass('d-none');
                $(".loadingContentModal").removeClass('d-none');
                $("#pullBankSlips").modal('show');
            },
            xhr: function() {
                var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

                xhr.upload.onprogress = function(event) {
                    let uploadedBytes = event.loaded / event.total;
                    console.log(event.loaded);
                };

                return xhr;
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var count = 0;
                $(data).each(function(e) {
                    count++;

                    $("#pullBankSlips #bankSlipsContent").append(
                        '<input type="hidden" name="bankSlips[]" value="' + data[e]['bank_slip']
                        .id +
                        '"><div class="row mb-3"><label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Cliente:</label><div class="col-sm-10"><input readonly value="' +
                        data[e]['client'].name +
                        '" type="text" class="form-control"></div></div><div class="row mb-3"><label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">E-mail:</label><div class="col-sm-10"><input value="' +
                        data[e]['financial_email_client'].value +
                        '" type="email" class="form-control" name="emailClients[]"></div></div><div class="row mb-3"><label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Boleto:</label><div class="col-sm-10"><input readonly value="' +
                        data[e]['bank_slip'].original_name +
                        '" type="text" class="form-control"></div><div class="d-flex mt-1 justify-content-end"><a href="{{ env('APP_URL') }}/storage/' +
                        data[e]['bank_slip'].file_path +
                        '" target="_blank">Visualizar Boleto</a></div></div>');

                    if (count != data.length) {
                        $("#pullBankSlips #bankSlipsContent").append("<hr/>");
                    }
                });
            }
        }).done(function() {
            $(".loadingContentModal").addClass('d-none');
            $("#pullBankSlips .modal-header, .modal-body, .modal-footer").removeClass('d-none');
        });
    }
```

Eu limitei a velocidade no console do navegador e mesmo assim continua dando 100%.